# programa em c duvida - busca dentro do for

Tags: c, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá! Sou estudante de ciências da computação e estou desenvolvendo um programa de uma livraria com menu. O programa funciona todo que é uma beleza por excessão de uma coisa...

Quando faço uma busca por autor não consigo colocar quando o autor não foi encontrado
quando adiciono o else ele encontra o autor e depois aparece não encontrado para cada livro cadastrado.

poderiam me ajudar?

segue meu codigo de busca

```
case 'a':

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\ndigite o AUTOR do livro que procura\n");

    gets(autor_pesquisa);



    for(i=0; i<=cadlivrosmax; i++){
        retorno = strcmp(autor_pesquisa,quantidades[i].autor);
        if(retorno == 0){
            printf("Codigo: %d\n",i+1);
            printf("Titulo: %s\n",quantidades[i].titulo);
            printf("Autor: %s\n",quantidades[i].autor);
            printf("Estilo: %s\n",quantidades[i].estilo);
            printf("Preco: %f\n\n\n",quantidades[i].preco);
        }   


        else{
            printf("\n autor não encontrado\n");
        }                                           
    }

break;
```

Comment: Note que seu `if` está dentro do loop. Uma possibilidade é você interromper o loop quando achar e ao final do loop testar se encontrou ou não.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia fazer assim:

```
case 'a':

fflush(stdin);
printf("\ndigite o AUTOR do livro que procura\n");

gets(autor_pesquisa);


for(i = 0; i <= cadlivrosmax; i++){

    retorno = strcmp(autor_pesquisa,quantidades[i].autor);

    if(retorno == 0){
        break;
    }

}

if(retorno == 0){

    printf("Codigo: %d\n",i+1);
    printf("Titulo: %s\n",quantidades[i].titulo);
    printf("Autor: %s\n",quantidades[i].autor);
    printf("Estilo: %s\n",quantidades[i].estilo);
    printf("Preco: %f\n\n\n",quantidades[i].preco);

} else {

    printf("\n autor não encontrado\n");

} 

break;
```